# Handle NULL in Datareader

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader, datareader

This is the code I' using for reading data from sql through DataReader. It gives Error when there is a NULL in table. How to handle it?

I tried

```
c.ActualWeight= dr[0] as float? ?? default(float);
```

The problem with this is that it is successful in Handling NULLs but the result is Always 0 even if the sql database has value 1 in that field.

```
{ 
    List<Inventory_Connector> LC = new List<Inventory_Connector>();
    string ConString = "data source=DELL\\SQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=Camo;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Top 17 * from Inventory_Connector", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        c.ActualWeight = float.Parse(dr[0].ToString().Trim());
    }

    LC.Add(c);
}

dr.Close();
con.Close();
return LC;
```

Comment: What type has the first column of `Inventory_Connector` ?

Comment: Just a comment, you are selecting the top 17 rows, and putting the value of each row into c.ActualWeight, before adding `c` to the list and re-initialising it. This means your actual weight will only be the last enter from your DB.

Comment: Also do not forget to call `Dispose` methods for `con`, `cmd` and `dr`. Or better yet, use `using` statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`SqlDataReader.IsDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check for null values out of a data reader. C# `null` and `DBNull` are different.

```
 c.ActualWeight = 
     dr.IsDBNull(0) 
     ? default(float) 
     : float.Parse(dr[0].ToString().Trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
if (dr.IsDBNull(0))
   c.ActualWeight = default(float);
else
   c.ActualWeight = float.Parse(dr[0].ToString().Trim());
```

Comment: You don't need GetOrdinal, IsDBNull takes in an Ordinal position

Comment: @DaveShaw Does it? I use it so rarely, I recall needing it way back. I'll edit my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
c.ActualWeight = (dr[0] != DBNull.Value) ? float.Parse(dr[0].ToString().Trim()) 
                                         : default(float)
```

use the `DBNull.Value` to check for null values.